# Data from input form to controller

Tags: forms, symfony

To generate form I use 
`{{ form_rest(form) }}` 
It generates me a html:

```
<label class="required" for="findclient_client_number">Client number</label>
<input id="findclient_client_number" type="text" required="required" name="findclient[client][number]">
```

At controller I am trying to access data by:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new FindClientType(), new FindClient());
$form->bind($this->getRequest()); 
$clientnumber = $form->get('number')->getData();
return $this->render(
                    'MyDefaultBundle:Default:client.html.twig', array('clientnumber' => $clientnumber)
    );
```

And get error:

> Child "[number]" does not exist.

How to get submitted data from that field ?
Thanks for any help...

Comment: What version of symfony are you using? Can you show more code from the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the request to the form first. There is a `Form::bind()` method that will do this for you.

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ClientType());

if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $form->bind($this->get('request'));
    $form->getData(); // Will return bound data
}
```

You can also get data directly from the request in your controller.

```
$this->get('request')->request->get('name')
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Ryans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16660764/2084176) you are using an object (`FindClient`). So simply bind your form, get data and handle with your `FindClient` object to get your number.

```
$form = $this->createForm(new FindClientType(), new FindClient());
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $form->bind($this->getRequest());
    $data = $form->getData(); // Will return bound data
    $clientnumber = $data->getNumber() // assuming your getter for the number
}
```

Comment: Please would you be so kind and try to show me how code of `Find client` should look like? I am kind out of point..

Comment: I assumed you have already a `FindClient` class, as you showing it, in your posted code.

Comment: I have got. But the code is totall crap. I need to implement getNumber. Cause I got  `FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method My\DefaultBundle\Form\Model\FindClient::getNumber()`

Comment: Don't know, your responsibility. If you don't know, go back to the symfony book and read about entitys